# How do I launch a different webcam program(Now it is Cheese) from the system indicator?

Tags: indicator, webcam

I am using Ubuntu 11.10, When i click Webcam Option in Right-Top Drop-Down menu, Ubuntu Software Center opens showing Cheese Webcam Central page, 'Cheese" in Ubuntu 11.10 is glitchy so i have installed Camorama, Is there any way to make Camorama open instead of Cheese when i press that Option

[image]

Comment: Usually one webcam software is needed. Therefore, if you wanna use Camorama as your default webcam software, uninstall Cheese and use Camorama instead.

Comment: ive not at all installed cheese,

Answer (score 2):

The most practical way I found was to create a symlink /usr/local/bin/cheese pointing to /usr/bin/guvcview